# Cannot use ngIf in cell renderer

Tags: angular, ag-grid, angular9

I'm trying to have buttons that are displayed or hidden, depending on various conditions in a custom cell renderer.

Here's the template of my renderer:

```
<div class="btn-toolbar" style="justify-content: flex-start; display: flex;">
    <button (click)="editStage()" type="button" class="btn-xs btn btn-primary btn-default btn-space"><span class="fas fa-edit"></span></button>
    <button (click)="gotoSteps()" type="button" class="btn-xs btn btn-primary btn-default btn-space"><span class="fas fa-code-branch"></span></button>
    <button *ngIf="stage.order > 0 && nbrStages > 1" (click)="moveUp()" type="button" class="btn-xs btn btn-primary btn-default btn-space"><span class="fas fa-arrow-up"></span></button>
    <button *ngIf="orderPlusOne < nbrStages && nbrStages > 1" (click)="moveDown()" type="button" class="btn-xs btn btn-primary btn-default btn-space"><span class="fas fa-arrow-down"></span></button>
   <button (click)="deleteStage()" type="button" class="btn-xs btn btn-primary btn-default btn-space"><span class="fa fa-trash-alt"></span></button>
</div>
```

And here's the component code

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-workflow-stage-buttons',
    templateUrl: './workflow-stage-buttons.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./workflow-stage-buttons.component.css']
})
/** workflow-stage-buttons component*/
export class WorkflowStageButtonsComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
    /** workflow-stage-buttons ctor */
    constructor() {

    }

    params: any;
    stage: WorkflowStage;
    nbrStages: number;
    orderPlusOne: number;
    

    refresh(params: any): boolean {
        return false;
    }

    agInit(params: import("ag-grid-community").ICellRendererParams): void {
        this.params = params;
        this.stage = <WorkflowStage>this.params.data;
        this.nbrStages = this.params.api.getRenderedNodes().length;
        this.orderPlusOne = this.stage.order + 1;
    }

    afterGuiAttached?(params?: import("ag-grid-community").IAfterGuiAttachedParams): void {

    }
}
```

I get the following error when the cell is being rendered though:

```
Can't bind to 'ngIf' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.
```

Outside of the cell renderer logic, I can do an `ngIf` on a button anywhere else in my application. It seems that something isn't loaded properly when in the context of the cell renderer.

I've tried adding `WorkflowStageButtonsComponent` in my module's declarations and adding `CommonModule` in my module's imports and that didn't do the trick.

Any ideas ?

EDIT: I'm using ag-grid-angular@23.2.1

Comment: you need to import [CommonModule](https://angular.io/api/common/CommonModule) in the module where your component is declared

Comment: @v.kostenko I only have one module for the entire application for the moment

Comment: You can wrap the buttons in ng-container and add the *ngIf statement to that as a quick fix. This is abnormal behavior though.

Comment: @FrancisDucharme could you provide an example please on plunker/stackblitz etc I've just tried to use *ngIf in [official example](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-cell-rendering-components/#example-rendering-using-angular-components) and it's working well

Answer (score 5, accepted):

import `CommonModule` from the module that is providing your component.

```js
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule], // <- importing CommonModule
    declarations: [WorkflowStageButtonsComponent]
    ...
}) 
export class MyComponentModule {} // This is the module where you define your component
```

Comment: weirdly, this started working after I went for a coffee and came back... Maybe the webpack needed to refresh/recompile or something while I was away? I didn't work right away though...